# Python-3.4 Scapy Sending ARP packet

Tags: python-3.x, scapy

I have this script:

```
from scapy.all import *
def ip1(ip):
    pkt = send(ARP(op=ARP.who_has, psrc="192.168.5.51", pdst=ip))
    x = sniff(filter="arp", count=10)
    print (x.summary())
    print ("done")

ip1("192.168.5.46")
```

Now, it gets stuck at the send line: it says:

```
 . Sent 1 packets.
```

But doesn't continue the script (and it doesn't really send the packet). When I ctrl+c the script, THEN it send the packet and print the x.summary() and prints done ....  I wish to know why
Thanks in advance.

Edit: would the answer be about sr(), sr1(), srp(), and srp1() functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "`. Sent 1 packets.`" output actually proves that the script sent the packet. However, it is stuck on the `sniff` function, until `Ctrl-C` is hit. This function triggers an endless sniff operation, unless the `timeout` argument specifies otherwise.

[*Scapy*'s official API documentation](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/files/scapydoc.pdf) reads:

> `timeout`: stop sniffing after a given time (default: `None`).